# Mongodb nested query doesn't give result when operators are involved

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Rrunning the following snippet I would expect all of the finds to return the same result, however the middle on does not find any elements. Why doesn't the second case find anything and is there any way to use the nested element notation instead of dot notation with the mongodb operators?

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
db = client['db']
collection = db["test_collection"]
collection.insert_one({"data": {"foo": "bar"}})

# {'_id': ObjectId('633aad8b587bc8057e240c96'), 'data': {'foo': 'bar'}}
print(collection.find_one({"data": {"foo": "bar"}}))

# None
print(collection.find_one({"data": {"foo": {"$in": ["bar"]}}}))

# {'_id': ObjectId('633aad8b587bc8057e240c96'), 'data': {'foo': 'bar'}}
print(collection.find_one({"data.foo": {"$in": ["bar"]}}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't the second case find anything?

The second query is using embedded document syntax to search for documents. As you mentioned, dot notation is the alternative syntax. Both are documented [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#match-an-embedded-nested-document).

Each approach has different semantics. The second query that you are asking about is searching for a document that has *exactly* this object for its `data` field:

```
{
  foo: {
    $in: [
      "bar"
    ]
  }
}
```

Check out [this playground demonstration](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-SdmjLAxQ2B) which shows this behavior with more example documents.

Of course that's not what you want which is one of the reasons the alternative dot notation syntax is available.

> is there any way to use the nested element notation instead of dot notation with the mongodb operators?

As written, the answer to that question is: no. As we explored above, querying using embedded syntax results in the following semantics (taken from the documentation):

> Equality matches on the whole embedded document require an *exact* match of the specified `<value>` document, including the field order.

Usage of query operators, which aren't intended for this syntax, is going to result in them getting interpreted as literal field names when searching the collection. But even your first example query probably isn't generally useful as the document embedded in `data` could not have any other fields as demonstrated in [this playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lj1pjJFkHkA)

Comment: I would separately be curious about the motivation for the question, especially the latter one.  Was this just curiosity that came from the discovery of the different syntax options?

Comment: I originally tried to use the nested query because it seemed intuitive to me, but since it wasn't working I read this https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#embedded-field-specification and nothing on that makes me think that the two different notations would behave differently, which lead to my confusion and this question.

Comment: Oh wow that is confusing/misleading!

Comment: Ah, rereading that section is specifically about _projection_ syntax. What this question is concerned with is semantics for querying syntax, which is what the link in this answer points toward. Still a bit nuanced, but ultimately I think everything here is 'technically correct'